# converting view from MySQL to ORACLE

Tags: oracle, view

I am currently trying to update a software to be able to connect to multiple databases.
So far it only supports MySQL but I am trying to connect it to a Oracle DB.

So far all conversions have worked really well. The only problem I stepped into was when I was trying to convert the script for a view.

My converted Version looks like this:

```
SELECT c.company_id AS company_id,
       c.company_name AS company_name,
       c.street || ' ' || c.house_number AS street,
       c.city AS city,
       c.country AS country,
       'DE' AS iso,

  (SELECT count(0)
   FROM proofheader lleph
   WHERE ((lleph.issuer_company_id = c.company_id)
          AND (lleph.customer_company_id = p.customer_company_id))) AS lle,

  (SELECT count(0)
   FROM proofheader ihkph
   WHERE ((ihkph.issuer_company_id = c.company_id)
          AND (ihkph.customer_company_id = p.customer_company_id)
          AND (ihkph.ihk = 1))) AS ihk,

  (SELECT count(0)
   FROM proofheader reminderph
   WHERE ((reminderph.issuer_company_id = c.company_id)
          AND (reminderph.customer_company_id = p.customer_company_id)
          AND (reminderph.status_of_proof IN ('FIRST_REMINDER',
                                              'SECOND_REMINDER',
                                              'THIRD_REMINDER')))) AS reminder,
       0 AS reminderlevel,
       p.customer_company_id AS customer_company_id
FROM (company c
      LEFT JOIN proofheader p on((p.issuer_company_id = c.company_id)))
WHERE (c.issuer = 1)
GROUP BY c.company_id,
         p.customer_company_id
HAVING (count(DISTINCT p.proofheader_id) > 0);
```

SQL Developer gives me an error when trying to run it that it is "not a GROUP BY expression".

After some research I learned that Oracle need all the SELECT fields to be present in the GROUP BY expression. SQL Developer even suggested a change to the script, after which the GROUP BY expression looks like this:

```
...
WHERE
  (c.issuer = 1)
GROUP BY
  c.company_id,
  p.customer_company_id,
  c.company_name,
  c.street,
  c.city,
  c.country,
  'DE',
  0
HAVING
  (count(DISTINCT p.proofheader_id) > 0);
```

If I run this script I still get the error "not a GROUP BY expression".

As far as I can tell I need to include **all** the SELECT fields in the group by. But if I try to extend the expression to this:

```
...
GROUP BY
  c.company_id,
  p.customer_company_id,
  c.company_name,
  c.street,
  c.city,
  c.country,
  'DE',
  0,
  ihk,
  lle,
  reminder
HAVING
  (count(DISTINCT p.proofheader_id) > 0);
```

I get an error that reminder and lle are invalid identifiers.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for die advice. I changed it but that sadly doesn't fix the problem. Would have been great though if such a small thing would have fixed it.

Comment: The `left join` seems unnecessary as it's effect is cancelled by your having clause.

Comment: I think you can simplify the whole query by using a derived table and doing the grouping there by applying conditional aggregation. That removes you from the need to group the complete query: Something like this: http://dpaste.com/3S1GR00